# How many iterations does it take to converge to 1 (or lesser)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, asymptotics, computational-mathematics

**Problem:**

Given a positive integer $N$,
we perform the following algorithm:

Repeat till $N > 1$:
$\ \ \ N=N-\pi(N)$;

where $\pi(N)$ is number of prime numbers less than or equal to $N$.

As a second part to this question I also need sum of all N's generated at each iteration.

**My thoughts:**
I am sensing something similar to harmonic like $N+N/2+N/3+N/4+...$
but decay is slower.

I wrote a script for various N, here are the results:

- N=10
  ,iterations=3
  ,sum=20
- N=100
  ,iterations=9
  ,sum=330
- N=1000
  ,iterations=19
  ,sum=5141
- N=10000
  ,iterations=34
  ,sum=72539
- N=100000
  ,iterations=55
  ,sum=949457
- N=1000000
  ,iterations=80
  ,sum=11778194
- N=10000000,
  iterations=111,
  sum=140785844
- N=100000000,
  iterations=147,
  sum=1638425639
- N=1000000000
  iterations=189
  sum=18690825960
- N=10000000000,
  iterations=236,
  sum=209971947776
- N=100000000000,
  iterations=288,
  sum=2330297134561
- N=1000000000000,
  iterations=345,
  sum=25608180074716

From data as I can see number of iterations is relatively small but having said that the difference in number of iterations between $10^7$ and $10^{12}$ is not much,

**Summarise:**

Not looking for closed form, looking for asymptotics(with detailed derivation)

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  For a problem like this, I'd expect to see a substantial study of examples.  Note:  I don't understand your stopping criterion. Presumably you mean "till $N=1$", no?

Comment: Another natural place to start is consider iterations of $x-\frac x{\ln x}$.  Not the same, exactly, but might be quite close.

Comment: Do you mean ‘do while’?

Comment: Well, $N$ starts out $>1$ so "repeat until $N>1$" doesn't seem to be what you want.  I assume you mean "repeat until $N=1$".

Comment: Beyond that, I'm not sure what you are hoping for here.  I seriously doubt that there is a known closed form for the number of iterations, nor for the sum you mentioned.  Maybe asymptotics can be derived from the prime number theorem, as I sketched before, but...well, the $\pi(x)\sim \frac x{\ln x}$ estimate isn't meant to work terribly well for small $x$.  Since there are so many small primes, my guess would be that the number of iterates of my function is greater than for yours, but maybe for very large $x$ that isn't all that significant.

Comment: Idea: Defining the sequence $x_1=N$ and $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n}{\log(x_n)}$ seems useful. This definition is also Newton's Method for a function $f(x)=\exp(\log^2(x)/2)$ with an initial guess of $N$. Could maybe estimate the number of iterations using this?

Comment: Your numbers show a superb quadratic $$\text{iter}=2.53184 \log_{10}^2(N)-1.71187  \log_{10}(N)$$ with $R^2=0.999938$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici please elaborate, if you feel comments is too small space to write you can convert it to an answer even if you feel its not complete.

Comment: This is just the result of a quadratic regression with no intercept based on your data points.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I am just looking for asymptotics, so I guess ML/stats model should do.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Now that I have reasonable understanding of the answer for this, can you also take a look at my other question(linked to this) and post results from your ML/stats model tool. I would appreciate if you also explain what Regression tool/code you are using. For asymptotics ML/stats are pefectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try iterating
$$
f(y) = y - \frac{y}{\log y}
$$
instead. Because $\pi(y)=y/\log y + O(y/\log^2y)$ this should be a reasonable first order estimate.

The basic idea is to see how many iterations of $f$ it takes to get from $x$ to $x/2$. Once we have this, just sum and you're done.

But once you're in $(x/2, x]$ everything is easier because $\frac{y}{\log y}$ is between $\frac{x}{2\log x}$ and $\frac{x}{\log(x/2)}$, so the number of iterations is between
$$
\frac{x}{2}\cdot\frac{\log(x/2)}{x} = \frac{\log(x/2)}{2} = \frac12\log x - \frac12\log2
$$
and
$$
\frac{x}{2}\cdot\frac{2\log x}{x} = \log x.
$$

So the number of iterations is (with $\ell = \lfloor\operatorname{lg}x\rfloor$ the binary logarithm rounded down) between
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\ell} \frac12\log(2^k)-\frac12\log2
= -\frac{\log2}{2}\ell + \frac{\log2}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\ell} k
= \frac{\log2}{4}\ell(\ell+1)-\frac{\log2}{2}\ell
= \frac{\log2}{4}\ell(\ell-1)
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\ell} \log(2^k)
= \log2\sum_{k=1}^{\ell} k
= \frac{\log2}{2}\ell(\ell+1)
$$
modulo a bit of fiddling around the endpoints.

To get a better constant, ro-do this argument with a smaller number than 2, or even use $1+\varepsilon$ and use limits.

For the original problem, then, the number of iterations should then be around $\asymp \log^2x$ with a proportionality constant perhaps around a third.